# In R's {collapse} package, how to achieve what dplyr::distinct() or base::unique.data.frame() do?

Tags: r

I'm new to the `{collapse}` R package, trying to find how to do the same thing that `dplyr::distinct()` or `base::unique.data.frame()` do: get the unique combinations over several columns.

For example:

```r
library(babynames)
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(collapse, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
#> collapse 1.6.5, see ?`collapse-package` or ?`collapse-documentation`
#> Note: stats::D  ->  D.expression, D.call, D.name

via_distinct <- babynames %>% distinct(sex, name)
via_collapse <- babynames %>% collap(sex ~ name)


nrow(via_distinct)
#> [1] 107973
nrow(via_collapse)
#> [1] 97310
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Only by number of rows we can see that `via_collapse` isn't giving the same output as `via_distinct`. Clearly, I'm not using `collapse()` correctly, or othwerwise there should be a different way to use `{collapse}` tools for this task.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

collapse has `funique` although note that collapse does not have its goal to be comprehensive but rather to provide functions where it can offer performance so, in general, it can't be expected that there will be a replacement for each function.

```
via_distinct <- babynames %>% distinct(sex, name) %>% arrange(sex, name)
via_collapse <- babynames %>% slt(sex, name) %>% funique(sort = TRUE)

identical(via_distinct, via_collapse)
## [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks! I agree with your statement. I rephrased my question. I didn't look for a 1:1 equivalent.

Comment: @Henrik, good point. One of my initial attempts (before posting the question) was to use `funique(cols = 1)` which gave an undesired output. So explaining how `cols` argument works will be helpful.

Comment: @Emman I hope you have already found the very nice [`collapse` documention starting page](https://sebkrantz.github.io/collapse/reference/index.html). A CTRL-F for 'unique' takes you to [`funique`](https://sebkrantz.github.io/collapse/reference/funique.html). There you find the method for `data.frame`: `funique(x, cols = NULL, sort = FALSE, ...)`. Then read about the `cols` argument: "compute unique rows according to a subset of columns. Columns can be selected using column names, indices, a logical vector".

Comment: Say you want to select unique rows of `mtcars` where uniqueness is determined based on columns 'cyl' and 'am', you could specify the columns with e.g. a character vector `funique(x = mtcars, cols = c("cyl", "am"))`